# PHP Unit console return code

Tags: selenium, phpunit, console-application

How can I make PHPUnit write to console **only** specific message depending on the success or error?
This is what I have so far:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    $this->setHost('host');
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setBrowserUrl('url');
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {

   $this->open("url");
    ...
   }
 }
```

### Generates output:

PHPUnit 3.7.26 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 9.59 seconds, Memory: 2.00Mb
OK (1 test, 0 assertions)

### Required Output:

OK or Error

Comment: The default command line does indicate an error or not.  I was unable to rely on ERRORLEVEL for batch file processing from the execution, so I captured the PHPUnit output, and then checked the line for Error/Failure text etc...  Looking at the pass line and then the errors and warnings allows you to determine success since the output is very consistent.

Comment: But the information i need is on the output(second line), i just need to get rid of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use exit status of PHPUnit and standard streams redirection

```
phpunit ./tests/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo OK || echo Error
```